# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')" error in Vue.js while using VueX

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Using VueX, I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')

I am not able to figure out why I am getting this error, I assume it might be because of the newer version, but not sure.

Code:

main.js

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import { store } from "./store.js";
import App from "./App.vue";

const app = createApp(App);
app.mount("#app");
app.use(store);
```

```js
import { createStore } from "vuex";

// Create new store instance

export const store = createStore({
  state() {
    return {
      toggle: false,
      count: 0,
    };
  },
});
```

```html
<template>
  <main class="paddings innerWidth n-container flexCenter">
    <div class="nav-options flexCenter innerWidth">
      <h1>VUE-FLIX</h1>
      <h2>{{ count }}</h2>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import "../NavBar/NavBar.css";
// import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: "NavBar",

  data() {
    return {
      name: "Vinoth",
    };
  },

  computed: {
    count() {
      return this.$store.state.count;
    },

    // ...mapState({
    //   count: (state) => state.count,
    // }),
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: What versions of Vue and Vuex?  Also, please include code from `main.js` showing how you import and add Vuex to your Vue instance.

Comment: vue3 version, vuex-4 vesrion

Comment: The problem is in `main.js`. The order in which you install plugins and mount your Vue instance is important.  **Install plugins first, then mount**, i.e. move `app.use` to be before `app.mount`

Comment: what kind of plugins install sir

Comment: Vuex is a plugin.  [app.use](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-use) installs it.  If you mount your app _before_ it's installed it won't work.  So repeating what I said before, move your `app.use` statement to be before `app.mount`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the plugin ordering answer provided by @youdu, I think you should change the store import line in main.js to eliminate the destructuring, so instead of:

```
import { store } from "./store.js";
```

you would have:

```
import store from "./store.js";
```

The store is the only export from store.js, so you don't want to use the destructuring syntax.